# Output sql output from bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I was using `OUTFILE`  command but due to permission issue and security risk I thought of dumping the output of shell to file but has got some error .
What I have tried

```
#This is a simple shell to connect to mysql db
cat  mysql -h "localhost" -u  "XXXXXXX" "-pXXXXXX"  standard_new2 << EOF
select * from cnhdatad limit 10;
EOF  ./sample2.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's incorrect output redirection syntax for heredoc.

Try this command:

```
mysql -h "localhost" -u  "XXXXXXX" "-pXXXXXX"  standard_new2 << EOF > ./sample2.txt
select * from cnhdatad limit 10;
EOF
```

Comment: 10x for the help I am not very used to shell

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you.